# A question about convergence of stochastic processes converging to a random walk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence, random-walks

Consider the following random walk $(y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z_+}$:

$$y_t = y_{t-1} + u_t,\quad (u_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z_+} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1), \quad (t \in \mathbb Z_+)$$

where $y_0, u_1, u_2,...$ are independent.

We know that the process is not stationary and non-ergodic. On the other hand, if $|a|< 1$, we have:
$$y_t = a y_{t-1} + u_t,\quad (u_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z_+} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1), \quad (t \in \mathbb Z_+)$$
is stationary and ergodic. Consider then the following sequence of stochastic processes: let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that, $|a_n|< 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $a_n \to 1$, as $n \to \infty$. So, for every $n \in \mathbb N$, define the process $(y_t^n)_{t \in \mathbb Z_+}$ as:
$$y^n_t = a_n y^n_{t-1} + u^n_t,\quad (u^n_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z_+} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1), \quad (t \in \mathbb Z_+)$$

So, I would like to know which metric we can use to determine whether the sequence of stochastic processes $(y^n_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ converges to the random walk $(y_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ defined above.

Comment: The question is not clear at all. First, the sequences should be indexed by $\mathbf{Z}_+$. Indexing by $\mathbf{Z}$ is not always possible. Next, you should say that $y_0,u_1,u_2\ldots$ are independent. Last which kind of convergence do you expect? For example, under your assumptions, the sequence of random variables $(Y^n_0,Y^n_1)$ does not converge in distribution to $(Y_0,Y_1)$.

Comment: I edited my question. In econometrics, these processes are used a lot. $a_n$ represents persistence and when $a_n$ tends to 1, many properties are lost such as stationarity and ergodicity. So then my curiosity arose if there is any metric that can handle this. In other words: how far or near are these two classes of processes?

Comment: What do you mean by "ergodic"?

Comment: You could try the Skorokhod topology, that is often a natural choice for comparing paths of stochastic processes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The ergodicity of stationary time series is generally defined as the almost sure convergence of sample moments to their respective population moments. There is another definition in the context of dynamic systems, which is closely related to the Birkhoff-Khinchin theorem. Regarding the Skorokhod topology, do you know if it can be used to check whether the distributions of two stochastic processes are close in distance? Do you have any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, naturally, that for each $n$ we have $y_0^n\to y_0$ (as $n\to\infty$) in distribution and $y_0^n$ is independent of $(u^n_t)$.

Then for each $T=0,1,\dots$ we have $Y^n_T\to Y_T$ in distribution, where $Y^n_T:=(y^n_0,\dots,y^n_T)$ and $Y^n_T:=(y_0,\dots,y_T)$. This follows because (say) for all $t=0,1,\dots$
$$y^n_t=a_n^t y^n_0+\sum_{k=1}^t a_n^{t-1-k}u_k$$
(which latter can be proved by induction on $t$), so that for all $T=0,1,\dots$
$$Y^n_T=(y^n_0,\dots,y^n_T)\to\Big(y_0,y_0+u_1,\dots,y_0+\sum_{k=1}^T u_k\Big)
=(y_0,\dots,y_T)=Y_T$$
in distribution.

The latter convergence is equivalent to the convergence of $d(P_{Y^n},P_Y)$ to $0$, where
$$d(P_{Y^n},P_Y):=\sum_{T=0}^\infty c_T\,
\frac{d_{LP}(P_{Y^n_T},P_{Y_T})}{1+d_{LP}(P_{Y^n_T},P_{Y_T})},$$
where (i) $(c_T)_{T=0}^\infty$ is any summable sequence of positive numbers and
(ii) $P_{Y^n_T}$ and $P_{Y_T}$ are, respectively, the distributions of $Y^n_T$ and $Y_T$ in $\mathbb R^{T+1}$ and $d_{LP}$ is the [Lévy–Prokhorov distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric#Properties) between such distributions.

Any metrics on the sets of all probability distributions over $\mathbb R^T$ can be used here in place of $d_{LP}$. If $y_0$ and the $y_0^n$'s are Gaussian, an especially convenient metric seems to be the Wasserstein $W_2$ metric, for which there is a rather simple [explicit expression](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-31/issue-2/A-class-of-Wasserstein-metrics-for-probability-distributions/10.1307/mmj/1029003026.full) in the Gaussian case.

Comment: Iosif, thanks for your interesting extension of the metric from finite dimensional distributions to a broader setting. I have two questions: (i) Can this extension be applied to other well-defined metrics in T-dimensional laws, such as the total variance metric for stochastic processes? (ii) Is it possible to use the existing literature on testing whether two observations from different finite dimensional distributions have close distributions to test for the proximity of two laws of stochastic processes based on finite observations, or are there additional precautions that need to be taken?

Comment: @PSE : (i) Yes, of course, any metrics on the sets of all probability distributions over $\mathbb R^T$ can be used in place of $d_{LP}$. If $y_0$ and the $y_0^n$'s are Gaussian, an especially convenient metric seems to be the Wasserstein $W_2$ metric, for which there is a rather simple [explicit expression](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-31/issue-2/A-class-of-Wasserstein-metrics-for-probability-distributions/10.1307/mmj/1029003026.full). (ii) I don't have ready references for such testing.